# Why doesn't Android Studio recognize Base64.encodeBase64?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libraries

I'm trying run the following code, however I cannot use `encodeBase64()`.
I've already tried to import such libraries using <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>.

[image]

How can I make it work?

Comment: If we're talking about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html, it doesn't have that method.

Comment: Try giving information about how it is NOT working ... what results you expect and what results you get, and why you think one should be the other.

Comment: Are you attempting to import http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html perhaps?

Comment: Please do not copy and paste code. Refer to the Android docs first.

Comment: I asked it because in Eclipse I had it working. However Android Studio does not. @Ahmad solved my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this:

```
String result = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

instead of what you are using, i also advise you to use:
`.getBytes("UTF-8");` instead of `data.getBytes();`
UTF-8 is always a better choice.
hope this will help you.